# Nginx Clean URLs don't work

Tags: 7, uri

I tried this: [How do I enable clean URLs with Nginx?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/how-do-i-enable-clean-urls-with-nginx)

And I tried this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-enable-clean-urls-with-nginx-for-drupal

So, I tried these:

```
 location / {
    index index.php;
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    expires max;
  }

  location @rewrite {
    # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
    # Else this rewrite block wouldn&#39;t be needed (GlobalRedirect)
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/www.example.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock; # fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
 }
```

And I tried these:

```
server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  example.org;

     location / {
         root   /path/to/drupal;
         index  index.php;
         error_page 404 = @drupal;
     }

     location @drupal {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
     }
 }
```

And clean URL's don't work. The site runs at ip address in a subdir 127.0.0.1/dev

It has its own config at /etc/nginx/sites-available/dev and symlinked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dev

This is my current `sites-available/default` config:

```
 root /var/www;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
 index index.html index.htm index.php;

 server_name _;

 location / {
 # First attempt to serve request as file, then
 # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
 # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
 expires max;
 }

 location @rewrite {
   # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
   # Else this rewrite block wouldn&#39;t be needed (GlobalRedirect)
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
 }

 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

 # With php7.0-cgi alone:
 # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 # With php7.0-fpm:

 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
 }
}
```

This is my current `sites-available/dev` config:

```
server {

        server_name dev;
        root /var/www/dev; ## <-- Your only path reference.

        # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg module
        # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
        gzip_static on;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # This matters if you use drush prior to 5.x
        # After 5.x backups are stored outside the Drupal install.
        #location = /backup {
        #        deny all;
        #}

        # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
        location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

        # No no for private
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

        # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
        # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
        # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }

  location / {
    index index.php;
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    expires max;
  }

  location @rewrite {
    # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
    # Else this rewrite block wouldn&#39;t be needed (GlobalRedirect)
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 }

        # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
        # This is for D6
        #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
        # This is for D7 and D8
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

}
```

I restart nginx server by running `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: what message do you get in your clean URLs config page? admin/config/search/clean-urls

Comment: that test failed, default message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about Drupal 7 right ? Try replacing

```
# For Drupal <= 6
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    expires max;
  }
```

by

```
# For Drupal >= 7
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; 
}
```

Then reload nginx.

This is a full example working vhost fir Drupal 7 :

```
server {

    listen 1.2.3.4:8000;
    server_name example.com www.example.com
    root /var/www/example.com /web;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    #Drupal private folder (see https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx#private-file-handling)
    location ^~ /sites/default/protected {
      internal;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; 
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        # PHP 7 socket location (change it to fit your config)
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { 
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
    # with a language prefix.
    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { 
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is 'listen' set to '1.2.3.4:8000' what's that? If I enter my server IP nginx won't restart. also what's '/web' part? Anyway I tried your config, but it breaks site now. CSS files won't load for example.

Comment: You have to change both IP and port accordingly to your config. By default port 80. I'm behind Varnish, this is why I wrote port 8000 in my example, sorry if it confused you.

Comment: I don't access the website via domain. I enter it via IP address e.g. http://127.0.0.1/dev and if I do that css files won't load and site loads all text in white. so I have to comment out the listen part to fix it. E.g. "listen 127.0.0.1:80;" (IP edited of course) and don't you need semi-colon at the end? It's not in your code. And clean urls still dont pass the test.

Comment: This is a bit out of the scope of your question :) I can't fully setup your remote  install, try to put these parameters in the server part at the beginning : `listen YOUR_SERVER_IP:80;`, then below `listen 80;`, then below if it was working `server_name dev;`, and below `root /var/www/dev;` , then the rest on sample nginx vhost.

Comment: awesome, works for drupal 7. Finally removed that annoying `?q`! Thanks for sharing